# If $f(x) = \log x$ then what will be the value of $f'(\log x)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> If $f(x) = \log x$ then what will be the value of $f'(\log x)$?

<sub>**Note:** I mentioned the question as it is was provided in my book and I, however, consider $f'(x)$ to be derivative with respect to $x$</sub>

---

The answer to the question according to chain rule should be

$$f'(\log x) = \frac{1}{\log x} \cdot \frac{1}{x}$$

according to me, however my book states that its answer is $\frac{1}{\log x}$ essentially the same as calculating the derivative and placing $\log x$ in place of $x$. Now which of these methods is the correct way to evaluate this and what wrong assumption is being considered in the wrong answer?

Comment: The book is correct. What you are calculating is $(f \circ \log)'(x)$ which is not the same as $f'(\log x)$.

Comment: I agree with @AustinShiner. Interesting question nevertheless

Comment: and in general, $f'(\ddot{\smile})=\frac{1}{\ddot{\smile}}$

Comment: No, it doesn't. $f'(y)= \frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x)=\log(x)$$

$$f'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\log(x)=\frac{1}{x}$$

$$f'(z)=\frac{1}{z}$$

$$f'(\log(x))=\frac{1}{\log(x)}$$

But:

$$f(\log(x))=\log(\log(x))$$

$$(f(\log(x))'=\frac{d}{dx}f(\log(x))=\frac{d}{dx}\log( \log(x))=\frac{1}{x\log(x)}$$

Answer (score 2):

What you need is not a formula, but an explanation.

There's a function f. It is defined as f(x) = ln x. It could be equally defined as f(y) = ln y, or f(x) = ln z, and so on and so on. The letter x in the definition is not important.

Then there is the function f', the derivative of f. We could write f'(x) = 1/x, or f'(y) = 1/y, or f'(z) = 1/z. All the same. The letter used is not important.

You are asked to calculate f'(log x). That is you apply the function f' with the argument log x. Since f'(x) = 1/x or f'(y) = 1/y, we have f'(log x) = 1 / (log x).